# What is the error in mysql procedure I am Getting Error in my code is anyone

Tags: mysql

[image]

```
BEGIN 


DECLARE i INT DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE J INT DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE msg varchar(255) DEFAULT null;
DECLARE msg1 varchar(255) DEFAULT null;
DECLARE s VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT null;




set i = select em_DOJ 
from employee_master
where MONTH(em_DOJ) = MONTH(NOW()) and DAY(em_DOJ) = DAY(NOW());
set j = (select TIMESTAMPDIFF(year,i,now()));
set msg1 = 'Congrats';
set msg = concat(msg1, j, 'Years Completed');

INSERT INTO time_line( tl_name, tl_dob, tl_message)
select em_first_name, em_DOJ, msg
from employee_master;
end
```

Why am I getting errors for this code. My intention is to transfer data from one table to another and to calculate the year at the same time. I am getting the error in this line.

```
set i = select em_DOJ 
from employee_master
where MONTH(em_DOJ) = MONTH(NOW()) and DAY(em_DOJ) = DAY(NOW());
```

Thanks For Solution.

Comment: what error please include error details

Comment: I have added image of the error

Comment: Don't post images of text - copy and paste the text here: [Why not upload images of code or errors on SO when asking a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/205233)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have a `WHERE` clause in the `INSERT ... SELECT ...` query, so it's selecting all rows from `employee_master`, and inserting a row into `time_line` for each of them with `msg`.

You don't need multiple queries. You should combine them all into a single `SELECT` so that the number of years in the message matches that employee.

```
INSERT INTO time_line (tl_name, tl_dob, tl_message)
SELECT em_first_name, em_DOJ, 
    CONCAT('Congrats on ', TIMESTAMPDIFF(year, em_DOJ, ,now()), ' Years Completed')
FROM employee_master
WHERE MONTH(em_DOJ) = MONTH(NOW()) and DAY(em_DOJ) = DAY(NOW());
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap the SELECT with braces:

```
set i = (select em_DOJ 
         from employee_master 
         where MONTH(em_DOJ) = MONTH(NOW()) and DAY(em_DOJ) = DAY(NOW()));
```

Additionally, this select does potentially return more than one result which would then cause an error.

Comment: Hey, Query Executed But The Message is not displaying in another table Main thing is to display message

Comment: @Karthik You're inserting a row into `timeline` for every employee in `employee_master`. Is that really what you want?

Comment: I am Not Inserting Every employee I am inserting an employee with respect to the date if the person has the birthday today then that time I am inserting the values.

Comment: There's no `WHERE` clause in the last `SELECT`, so it selects all rows in `employee_master`.

Comment: In i  I am taking year through that year i am calculating years with current year and storing it in the j

Comment: @Karthik The query that sets `i` selects `em_DOJ` of every employee whose anniversary is today. How can you set `i` to multiple values? Then when you do the `INSERT`, you're not selecting the employees with the current anniversary.

Comment: Is there any alternative way to do that in procedure